# Building boost and changing output dir/filename

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to build boost via Boost.Build from the cmd line - https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.overview.invocation

I want to have boost output my files at a certain folder and depending on address model + variant (debug/release 32/64) have a different name.

I tried something like this:

```
b2 --libdir=C:\ serialization filesystem system toolset=msvc-12.0 variant=debug,release threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static address-model=64,32 architecture=x86
```

It just builds to the default output path... and there seems to be no option to rename output files.

Also tried "--build-dir" with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try with giving path with quotes as shown in here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#invoke-b2

You can also try giving stagedir flag. --stagedir=directory

Comment: Tried it; neither works, it just silently uses the default path